# Android Studio: access a listview element in the xml file from the java file.

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-studio

I am working in android studio and I created a listview in the xml layout file. How can I access that listview in my java file in order to attach an arrayadapter to it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a layout file `mylayout.xml` with this

```
<ListView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>
```

In the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    ...
    ListAdapter myAdapter = new MyListAdapter(...);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);  //use the id specified in the layout file
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```